# Caused by error in `check_match()`: ! `match` must be a character vector of non empty strings

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So, the issue that I've got is that I am trying to transform a series of numbers which appear to me in scientific notation, say 1.39+e14, into single numbers which should indicate an age, ranging from 9 to 18.

My code is as follows:

```
df %>% 
mutate(age, starts_with(c("9." == "9", "1.0" == "10", "1.1" == "11", "1.2" == "12", "1.3" == "13", "1.4" == "14", "1.5" == "15", "1.6" == "16", "1.7" == "17", "1.8" == "18")))
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..2 = starts_with(...)`.
Caused by error in `check_match()`:
! `match` must be a character vector of non empty strings.
Backtrace:
1. FinalAssignment %>% ...
7. tidyselect::starts_with(...)
8. tidyselect:::check_match(match)
Error in mutate(., age, starts_with(c("9." == "9", "1.0" == "10", "1.1" == : 

Caused by error in `check_match()`:
! `match` must be a character vector of non empty strings.
```

I really do not understand what is going on here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `start_with` is the function to choice column, not to replace the value.It's easier to answer if you show which `class(df$age)` return numeric or character.

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful comment, @cuttlefish44 ! The class is numeric.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that I did not express myself correctly.

The thing is that MS Excel messed up quite seriously with the numbers, and the length of them was different in each case.

This solution (though it may not be necessarily the most elegant one) worked for me:

```
 df$age <- gsub('\\.', '', df$age)

 df$age <- as.numeric(df$age)

 df<- df%>% 
 mutate(age2 = floor(age / (10^9)))

 df$age2 <- substr(df$age2,1,2)
```

Just in case this may be of use to some other Stack Overflow user.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe scientific notation confued you (it is just notation). Your age is `numeric`, not `character`.
(and `start_with` is the function to choice column, not to replace the value)

As far as I see, what you want is

```
df %>% 
  mutate(age2 = floor(age / (10^13)))
```

Comment: Thank you, @cuttlefish44 ! Do check my own answer, though. I should have expressed myself with more precision, probably. Many thanks in any case!